# Include file within an include file stored above the website root - not working

Tags: php, include

I'm including this file to send email via swift mail
require_once '../../../../../directory-above-root/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

I'm getting the error require_once(): open_basedir restriction in effect. which I guess means it's trying to access a directory that is WAY to high up the directories and so can't be accessed.

Even though this path works when it is included in another file in the website it won't work when included in another file.  The path should then become this to work properly: 
require_once '../../directory-above-root/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

Trouble is this file is included within a file that's included in this page so I need a way of pointing to the directory in an absolute way.  (I hope this makes sense!)

The directory-above-root is a directory above the website directory (I use this because the file contains the login details for my email).

I think I need something like this:

define( 'ROOT_DIR', dirname(**FILE**) );
require_once ROOT_DIR.'../directory-above-root/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) :

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../directory-above-root/swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I've still love to know the answer to this but have found a way around my problem by not including a file within a file within a file.
So problem solved!